# Add arrow pointing from one table cell to another

Tags: arrows

I have a simple table where I would like to add arrows pointing from certain cells to other cells. In the example below, I would like to add one vertical arrow going from `Start1` to `Finish1` and one horizontal arrow going from `Start2` to `Finish2`. What is the best way to do this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
    \doublespacing
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l l}
Word & Start1\\
Word & Finish1\\
Finish2 & Start2\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Simple

Just an idea: Use an extra row and an extra column.

The following example does not change the placement of text in the `tabular`.

#### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{setspace,calc}
\doublespacing
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l c l}
    Word    &              & Start1                                       \\
            &              & \makebox[\widthof{Start1}][c]{$\downarrow$} \\
    Word    &              & Finish1                                      \\
    Finish2 & $\leftarrow$ & Start2                                       \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

#### Output

[image]

## TikZ

You could also use TikZ with all its possibilities.

### `tabular` + `remember picture`/`overlay`

#### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{setspace,tikz}
\newcommand*{\tn}[2]{\tikz[baseline,remember picture]\node[inner sep=0pt,anchor=base] (#1) {#2};}
\doublespacing
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l l}
    Word             & \tn{s1}{Start1}  \\
    Word             & \tn{f1}{Finish1} \\
    \tn{f2}{Finish2} & \tn{s2}{Start2}  \\
\end{tabular}
\tikz[remember picture,overlay,shorten >=.3333em,shorten <=.3333em]
    \path[->] (s1.south) edge (f1.north -| s1.south) (s2) edge (f2);
```

\end{document}

#### Output

[image]

### `\matrix` (without `tabular`)

#### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{setspace,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\doublespacing
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[name=m,nodes={anchor=base west},matrix of nodes,row sep={2em,between origins},column sep=\tabcolsep]{
    Word & Start 1 \\
    Word & Finish1 \\
    Finish2 & Start 2 \\
};
\path[->] (m-1-2.south) edge (m-2-2.north -| m-1-2.south) (m-3-2) edge (m-3-1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

#### Output

[image]

Comment: I went with the tikz remember picture/overlay option, but slightly simplified some of the options (looking in the pgf manual and doing some trial and error). But I wouldn't have gotten anywhere if I weren't equipped with your solution from the start.