# Increase the arc in a TikZ arrow

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

This question is a spin-off from [TikZ arrow misaligned in italicized text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98467/tikz-arrow-misaligned-in-italicized-text).

I'm drawing an arrow from one character to another within a word, using TikZ's `\path edge[]`. But the arrow's arc is so flat that it touches the arrowhead. Ideally, I would make the arc steeper. I assume I can do this by using TikZ's `arc` option (?), but I haven't been able to figure out how to properly use it, based on what I read in the pgf manual.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,tikz}
    \setsansfont{Linux Biolinum O}
\begin{document}
\textsf{\textit{ac\tikz[baseline, remember picture] \node[inner sep = 0pt, anchor = base] (finisharrow){e};rn\tikz[baseline, remember picture] \node[inner sep = 0pt, anchor = base] (startarrow){a};}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, shorten <=.2ex, shorten >=.2ex]
    \path[->, semithick](startarrow.70) edge[out = 90, in = 90] (finisharrow.70);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `loosenes=<value>` to increase the radius of the arc:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\textsf{\textit{ac\tikz[baseline, remember picture] \node[inner sep = 0pt, anchor = base] (finisharrow){e};rn\tikz[baseline, remember picture] \node[inner sep = 0pt, anchor = base] (startarrow){a};}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, shorten <=.2ex, shorten >=.2ex]
    \path[->, semithick](startarrow.70) edge[out = 90, in = 90, looseness=2] (finisharrow.70);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```