# Suggested package for a chart

Tags: charts

I am a recent LaTex user and I am trying to find a suitable package, and perhaps also some coding examples, for a chart I have to include. The chart is the following [image]

As I said I am a beginner at best in using LaTeX, so please apologize any inaccuracy.
Thanks to anybody contributing.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Maybe have a loot at the [`tikz-cd` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-cd).

Comment: You can find examples with code on TeXample.net, some useful tags are https://texample.net/tikz/examples/tag/graphs/ and https://texample.net/tikz/examples/tag/diagrams/.

Comment: Another good starting point could be https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98227/add-arrow-pointing-from-one-table-cell-to-another, especially the second part of the answer.